# Garden syntax for repeat

Tags: css, clojure

I found myself writing this

```
  [:.container2 {:display :grid
                 :grid-template-columns "repeat(10, 50px)"
                 :grid-template-rows "repeat(10, 50px)"}]
```

to be converted to css using garden.

Should `"repeat(10, 50px)"` be written in some Garden way instead of me writing the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely have to exclude `clojure.core/repeat` from your namespace, but you can use garden's `defcssfn`.

```
(require '[garden.core :refer [css]])
(require '[garden.def :refer [defcssfn]])

(defcssfn repeat)

(css [:.container2 {:display :grid 
                    :grid-template-columns (repeat 10 "50px") 
                    :grid-template-rows (repeat 10 "50px")}]) 

=>    ".container2 {  display: grid;
                      grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 50px);
                      grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 50px);\n}"
```

OR

```
(def my-custom-repeat (repeat 10 "50px")

(css [:.container2 {:display :grid 
                    :grid-template-columns  my-custom-repeat
                    :grid-template-rows     my-custom-repeat}])

=>    ".container2 { display: grid;
                     grid-template-columns:  repeat(10, 50px);
                     grid-template-rows:     repeat(10, 50px); }"
```